# Facebook SDK for android download always failing

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, download

I am trying to download facebook SDK from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/downloads/

While downloading the total file size is unknown and the download ALWAYS fails after 9-13 MB.

I have tried different SDK releases, browsers, download managers, laptops, internet connections and it always fails.

Is anybody else having this issue? Is there another server hosting the latest SDK that I can download from?

Answer (score 2):

Refer to github website for sdk's. There is some bug with official website. You can download all releases/versions from here https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/releases

Comment: I couldn't complete my answer. I have edited it. This will solve your problem. As far as i can understand you are pointing to bug. But if you need other releases you can always use  https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/releases . I dont know how did it fail for you.!

Answer (score 1):

I do have the same issue bro. But I just found this and I shall download it.. But i dont think its the latest version though. https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk